# How to avoid invalid token when converting binary to decimal

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know there is a built-in function converting binary to decimal but I thought I challenge myself and make my own.

Here are the codes:

```
def binaryToDecimal(binary):
    binaryList = list(str(binary))
    exponent = len(binaryList) - 1
    decimal = 0

    for char in binaryList:
        bit = int(char)
        decimal += bit * (2 ** exponent)
        exponent -= 1

    print(decimal)
```

The problem is, i know if I want to begin my binary with 0, I have to use 0b prefix to avoid an invalid token but it leads me to a problem. It doesn't convert the last 1 on the left

```
binaryToDecimal(0b010001110)
```

So it outputs 14 instead of 142

How do i fix that? Also is there a way I can just say

```
binaryToDecimal(010001110)
```

without getting an invalid token without using 0b prefix?

I'm using Python 3.5

Comment: I'm not sure if you are aware, but `0b010001110` is not represented internally any different from `142`. They are both stored as perfectly ordinary integers. `list(str(0b010001110))` just gives you `['1', '4', '2']`.

Comment: `list(str(0b010001110))` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: What they said. You are getting 14 because `exponent` starts at 2, and 14 = 4*1 + 2*4 + 2. If you _really_ want to do your own binary conversion function you'll need to pass the binary arg in as a string, eg `'010001110'`. Or, as Aaron suggests, a list of bits, which can be integers.

Comment: for the sake of this exercise, I'd pass your input as a string or a list of bits: `"010001110"` or `[0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0]`

Comment: Yeh, i taught about that too. I think "010001110" is a better way of doing it. Thanks

Comment: @ScottHunter: Please do **not** remove the generic `python` tag from Python questions! It makes the question invisible to people who are following the main Python tag page. And it means that people who answer the question & get upvoted won't make progress on their Python tag badges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre problem is mainly `binaryList = list(str(binary))`.
`str(0b010001110)` returns `'142'`, not `'0b101010'` as you might expect.

Consequently, `binaryList` is `['1', '4', '2']`.

A coincidence made that `1 * 2**2 + 4 * 2**1 + 2` equals 14, which gives the impression that you're function don't treat the last digit.

But, if you're running you're function with `0b101010` as input, you get `10`.

A solution to get the binary representation as string is to pass to `format`:

```
list("{0:b}".format(0b010001110))
```

Which returns

```
['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0']
```

Answer (score 1):

`0b010001110` is *already* an integer with the decimal value of 142. If you really want to do your own binary conversion function you'll need to pass the binary arg in as a string, eg '010001110', or as a list of bits, which can be strings, integers, or even the boolean values `True` and `False`.

Once you have the `str` vs `int` input issue resolved, there's a simpler way to do the conversion. There's no need to mess around with exponents: in the loop just bit-shift the current result one place to the left and insert the next bit. Like this:

```
def bin_to_int(bits):
    result = 0
    for b in bits:
        result = (result << 1) | int(b)
    return result

# Test
data = [
    '0',
    '1',
    '110',
    '001101',
    '10001110', 
    '000010001110', 
    '11000000111001',
]

for bits in data:
    print(bits, int(bits, 2), bin_to_int(bits))
```

**output**

```
0 0 0
1 1 1
110 6 6
001101 13 13
10001110 142 142
000010001110 142 142
11000000111001 12345 12345
```

My test code uses the built-in `int` constructor to do the conversion as well, to verify that my `bin_to_int` function is performing correctly.

This line, which does most of the work, uses bitwise operators,

```
result = (result << 1) | int(b)
```

but you can implement it with "normal" arithmetic operators, if you like

```
result = result * 2 + int(b)
```